# Android ImageView and Textview

Tags: android, layout, textview, imageview

[image]

I want to create layout like at picture but i don't have clue at all how to make like that..
Does anyone can give me a clue or alternative how to do that ?

Comment: use frame layout or you can use relative layout. with both having align parent top and textview with gravity center

Answer (score 0):

Split it like this.
Imageview and first textview in a linearlayout Horizontal.
and then this linearlayout Horizontal and second textview in a linear layout vertical.

[image: Edited]

Comment: i think about this solution before but i get long string from server how do i seperate those string into 2 text view, i cant seperate those string by fixed number because it will be different on every devices

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this could be to lay the `TextView` and then overlay the `ImageView` on it. I think a `RelativeLayout` with the `TextView` defined first and followed by the `ImageView` might do the trick. You can toggle the visibility of the `ImageView` but would need to ensure that any text written to the `TextView` is written after taking into account width of the `ImageView` so as to not obscure any text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding two textviews in a relative layout and in addition to that an imageview.
This might help you to get started.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/item_generator"
    android:background="#FF000000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title_val"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"        
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_title"
        android:textColor="#888"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_right_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```